# How can I block Pasting a Text into TextBox in windows store app?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-8.1-universal

We need to disable the pasting option in TextBox of XAML page. Because we are working on question and answers type for that we need to disable the pasting option.

Comment: I always think that it is very annoying when pasting is disabled. I like to type out longer answers in proper text editors and then paste them into text fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend against disabling copy/paste. Disabling those options in text fields serves little more than annoying the user.

However, if you are to prevent Ctrl+C / Ctrl+V combinations, you could use

1. The KeyDown event - if you get that combination you could, for example, clear the clipboard with the static method `Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard.Clear();`
2. *not tested:* [ShortcutsEnabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.shortcutsenabled(v=vs.110).aspx) property or [Paste](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.paste(v=vs.110).aspx) method, if they are available for the textbox in your project type, might be enough.

EDIT: Make sure you disable the right click on your textbox as well.

Answer (score 0):

I handled the following events of the textbox, solved my problem.

```
private void TextBox_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

and

```
private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var ctrl = Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Control).HasFlag(CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down);
            if (ctrl) Clipboard.Clear();
    }
```